# Accessing query strings in https in node js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012

How to access the dynamic query strings and then store their key value pairs as JSON objects using `util.inspect` in http!

What about https?

I want to know the method to accessing the query strings in https? 
My code looks like this

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
 qs = url.parse(req.url, true);
});
```

Comment: And what does your code look like at the moment?

Comment: My code is in office ! Will post tomorrow positively ! I used util. Inspect function and url.parse function by using url and util package in http ! But the same method doesn't output same with https

Comment: @Sirko now please suggest solution !! Thanx In advance

Comment: Is your node server even running https? Doesn't look like it from your code sample.

Comment: You have to parse either the URL or the message body to get the query string. The default node implementation does not wrap around this, but leaves that to the coder. If you do not want to do this by hand, use some library for it like http://expressjs.com/ .

Comment: @Paul my node server is perfectly running at http and when i tried to run my node server on https with certificate and key it is running fine but i am unable to get the query string from the url in https  with the help of the method that i used for http !

Answer (score 0):

```
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    qs = url.parse(req.url, true);
    res.write(util.inspect(qs.query));//this will print the query string on webpage in json format

    var s = QueryStringToJSON();

    res.end('\n');
    });
function QueryStringToJSON() {
    var pairs = qs.search.slice(1).split('&');

    pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');
        result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
    });

    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```